# Is there a quick/optimal way to get a list of unique values for particular key?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'd like to get all unique values in a collection for a particular key in a MongoDB. I can loop through the entire collection to get them:

```
values = []
for item in collection.find():
    if item['key'] in values:
        pass
    else:
        values.append(item)
```

But this seems incredibly inefficient, since I have to check every entry, and loop through the list each time (which gets slow as the number of values gets high). Alternatively, I can put all the values in a list and then make a set (which I think is faster, though I haven't tried to figure out how to test speed yet):

```
values = []
for item in collection.find():
    values.append(item['key'])
unique_values = set(values)
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
unique_values = set([item['key'] for item in collection.find()])
```

But I'm wondering if there's a built-in function that wouldn't require looping through the entire collection (like if these values are stored in hash tables or something), or if there's some better way to get this.

Comment: looks [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`distinct()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) method does this. It returns an array(list) of the distinct values for the given key:

```
unqiue_values = collection.distinct("key")
```

Comment: Well, crap... that was easy. Clearly my googling was not what it should have been :-/. Apparently, I can't accept your answer for a few more minutes, but this works great!

Comment: @kevbonham The link there is to the pymongo collection object and methods. You should familiarise yourself with all the collection methods listed there.

Comment: thanks for that... if I read correctly, the entries below `distinct` are actually better answers to my actual problem, of which this is only a piece. I think I was about to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @kevbonham `.distinct()` does simple things, but you can look at `.aggregate()` for more complex groupings.

Comment: That looks cool and I'll need to look into that later, but I actually think the indexing functions are what I need for this problem... I was going to try to hack something together, but I think those will work even better... need to do some more reading though.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has a build-in method for this problem:

```
db.collection.distinct(FIELD)
```